# Setting a maximum height to a control, or getting ScrollView to respect other's MinimumHeightRequest

Tags: xamarin.forms

There is MinimumHeightRequest, but no MaximumHeightRequest for Views in Xamarin Forms. In its absence I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have two controls on my screen: a Signature and some legal-text. I would like the signature to take up much screen as possible, and for the legal-text to take the minimum space for itself but only up to half the parent height - and then to scroll if the text doesn't fit. I've tried `StackLayout` and `Grid` but neither quite do what I want in coping with all situations. If it existed simply setting a `MaximumHeightRequest` on the `ScrollingLegal` View would sort it out. But it doesn't. Here's what I've tried...

Controls defined as:

```
var Pad = new SignaturePadView() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    MinimumHeightRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Height / 2,
};

// Put legal text in a scroll view in case it doesn't fit on the screen.
var ScrollingLegal = new ScrollView { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, Content = new Label { Text = caption } };
```

Arranged with `StackLayout` like this it looks great on an iPad - text at the bottom of the screen signature taking up all the other space. On a small iPhone though, the text takes up all the screen and the signature appears to ignore the `MinimumHeightRequest` (this might be a bug I suppose?).

```
Stack.Children.Add(Pad);
Stack.Children.Add(ScrollingLegal);
```

I can add a `HeightRequest` to the `ScrollView` but then it always takes up X height. With a small amount of text I don't want that.

I have also tried a Grid:

```
var GridLayout = new Grid
{
    Padding = 1,
    RowDefinitions = {
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        },
    ColumnDefinitions = {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        },
};

GridLayout.Children.Add(Pad, 0, 0);
GridLayout.Children.Add(ScrollingLegal, 0, 1);
```

But that too always gives too much space to the text.

Is there a way of setting a Max Height?

Comment: Just a quick note to say I have not solved this properly - just hacked it by making up my own `HeightRequest` based on text length and screen size.